# Cometd does not receive messages on a Filtered Pushtopic for custom profile

Tags: fls, pushtopic, cometd

I have a lightning cometd. When I use pushtopic without filter for a custom profile it works. When I add filter, it does not receive the messages. If I login as system admin, the filtered pushtopic subscription receives messages.
This is a pushtopic on a custom object.
I have FLS as read write for all the fields  and create/modifyAll for Object level permission for this custom profile. 
I have enabled read permission on Pushtopic standard object permission.
What am I missing ?

PushTopic code

```
 PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic(); 
        pushTopic.Name = 'AssignmentNotification';
        pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id,user__c,userIdText__c FROM Assignment_Notification__c';       
        pushTopic.ApiVersion = 48.0;
        pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;  
        pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = false; 
        pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = false;
        pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = false;
        pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';  
        insert pushTopic;
```

Cometd Code

```
subscribe: function(component, event) { 
    // Get the empApi component
    const empApi = component.find("empApi");
    let sid = component.get("v.sid");
    let userId = component.get("v.userId");
    // Get the channel from the input box
    // const channel = "/topic/AssignmentNotification";               
    const channel = "/topic/AssignmentNotification?user__c="+userId;                         
    // Replay option to get new events
    const replayId = -1;

    // Subscribe to an event
    empApi
      .subscribe(
        channel,
        replayId,
        $A.getCallback(eventReceived => {
          // Process event (this is called each time we receive an event)
          console.log("Received event ", JSON.stringify(eventReceived));
          // this.handleShowModal(component);

          if (eventReceived.data.sobject.userIdText__c == userId)      
            this.openUtilNotification(component, event, eventReceived);
        })
      ) 
      .then(subscription => {
        // Confirm that we have subscribed to the event channel.
        // We haven't received an event yet.
        console.log("Subscribed to channel ", subscription.channel);
        // Save subscription to unsubscribe later
        component.set("v.subscription", subscription);
      }).catch((error => console.log('error on receiving message '+JSON.stringify(error))))
      .finally(()=> console.log('after receiving the message'));   
  }
```

Comment: Questions about implementation problems need to include a specific description of the problem (including exact errors and stack traces, if any) and **the code or metadata to reproduce the problem**. Please limit code inclusions to only the relevant elements, such as an MVR (minimum viable reproduction).

Comment: I have added code to the original question. Thanks for your feedback